# Use FacebookClient to look up 2.0-flavored profile IDs

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have been told that this endpoint can be used to determine the 2.0-flavored profile IDs for a Facebook user:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=REAL_ID&access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET
```

However, it's not clear to me how to successfully call this URL using FacebookClient.

```
facebookClient.Get("/?ids=REAL_ID")
```

and other similar attempts, give a message saying that REAL_ID is not recognized.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When you say "REAL_ID" do you mean the App Scoped User ID? Or the original generic Facebook User Id?

Comment: The endpoint's purpose is to look up the 2.0-style app-scoped ID given the original 1.0-style universal ID . . .